# Why am I getting a syntax error after my Json result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm using Json to retrieve data from a database, construct some html, and put it to the page, but I'm getting a syntax error after my 
 tag, which is the last tag in the string from my php file.

PHP:

```
if($QString == "")
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $categories="<a href=" . '"' . "?catID=" . $row['catID'] . '"' . ">" . $row['CatName'] . "</a><br>";
        echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . $categories;
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
var jSon = {};

$(function(){
    jQuery.jSon.getjSon();
});

jQuery.jSon = {
    getjSon : function () {
        $.getJSON('http://host6.spellnet.net/links/list.php?jsoncallback=?', function(json) {
        eval(json.data);
    });
}
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated. I'm getting closer and closer.

Comment: Looks like you are requesting a json return but are in fact returning html to jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a brace after `eval(json.data);`

Use this:

```
jQuery.jSon = {
    getjSon : function () {
        $.getJSON('http://host6.spellnet.net/links/list.php?jsoncallback=?', function(json){eval(json.data);});
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `getJSON` function; use `$.get` function instead. It has the same interface. Essentially, `getJSON` is trying to parse your function, which you don't need to do since it's JSONp.

All the best

Answer (score -2):

[JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) can help you find the problem. Paste in your result and see what it tells you.